# NGINX Reverse Proxy - Completely "shadowing" an URL subtree

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I have two servers, an application server running (backend) listening at example.com:8000 and an NGINX as reverse proxy server (frontend) listening at example.com:443.

The easy part is to configure NGINX so that all requests get proxied through to the backend system:

```
    location / {
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_pass       http://127.0.0.1:8000;
    }
```

This works like a charm; however there is another additional requirement, which I could not figure out how to realize yet. There is subtree of URLs at the backend system considered "ugly", say example.com:8000/my/ugly/path/, that should never be seen by the end user but instead "replaced" by example.com:443/pretty-path/. The problem is, that the backend system does not know about the "shadowing" of this subtree and generates URLs containing /my/ugly/path/ (both in HTTP headers and HTML content). So what is the best way to make /my/ugly/path/ transparently disappear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the sub_filter directive.  Note that nginx must be built to support this feature; use nginx -V to display configured options, look for --with-http_sub_module, or test your config file with nginx -t. Untested sample config below!

```
location / {
    sub_filter 'www.example.com/my/ugly/path'  
               'www.example.com/pretty/path';
    sub_filter_once off;
}
```

Ref. nginx sub_filter documentation [here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_sub_module.html).